# Integrate from $-b$ to $b$ in $\left\{(x,y,z) \mid |x|+|y|+|z| \leq b\right\}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, solid-geometry

So I know that $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and I also know that $\int_{-b}^{b}g(t)dt=a$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is some constant.
If we denote $V=\left\{(x,y,z) \mid |x|+|y|+|z| \leq b\right\}$ where $b>0$ is a real constant, I'm trying to calculate the following integral (as a function of $a$ and $b$):
$$
\iiint_{V}g(x+y+z)dxdydz
$$

---

To detail some of my previou efforts:

I tried a ton of different things but nothing seems to get me there, even though it seems to be close, somehow.
For instance: I listed out all the various planes we get by separating x,y,z into their cases (by octants) and composed them as simpler conditions, leaving me with:
$$
-b\leq x+y+z\leq b\\
-b\leq-x+y+z\leq b\\
-b\leq x-y+z\leq b\\
-b\leq x+y-z\leq b
$$
At this point I had attempted a few transformations, such as, for instance:
$$
u=x+y+z\\
v=-x+y+z\\
w=x-y+z
$$
Or equivalently (assuming no algebra shenanigans on my end),
$$
x=\frac{w-v}{2}\\
y=\frac{u-w}{2}\\
z=\frac{u+v}{2}
$$
Yielding a Jacobian determinant of $\frac{1}{4}$ and being continuously differentiable and everything (so a valid transformation – it's just a simple linear one but I made sure just in case/to practice, either way).
In this case, the new volume we're integrating over is:
$$
-b\leq u\leq b\\
-b\leq v\leq b\\
-b\leq w\leq b\\
-b\leq u-v-w\leq b
$$

My reasoning for attempting this was that I was trying to get the "$x+y+z$" ($g$'s argument) to become one variable that I can bound from $-b$ to $b$, but I could see no way to do this that didn't require me to integrate $g$ in some other, variable-dependant bounds before that, and that I couldn't think of how to do when all I know about $g$ is that it is continuous and that its integral specifically from $-b$ to $b$ is $a$.
I also tried drawing this post-transformation and saw that it was the volume trapped inside a cube with sides sized $2b$ and between two slopes ($-b\leq u-v-w\leq b$). This *seemed* promising, since I figured with another transformation I might potentially be able to somehow integrate over this seemingly-tame volume in a mannner that sums from $-b$ to $b$ so that I may use what I know about $g$'s integral, but... to no avail.

Comment: Thanks a lot in advance! This one's been a real head-scratcher for me.

Comment: If you look at the 2-d version, what can you say about the integral over the corresponding V section?  $\quad$ Alternatively, since the answer is likely independent of $g$, take the specific case of $ g(x) = a/2b$. What is the answer? Does this give you a hint of what to do?

Comment: Thanks a lot, @CalvinLin! If I take a specific $g$ I can indeed arrive at a final answer, but I'm not sure how to then prove its independence of $g$ (so long as it fulfills the conditions). I had considered that (and got $\frac{2}{3}ab^2$ as a solution by integrating over one octant and using the symmetry to justify multiplying it by 8), but was uncertain of how to proceed past that point, i.e how to prove that the same will happen for any continuous $g$

Comment: Trying to go down to 2-d, the best I could come up with is transformation using a rotation matrix of $\pi/4$ radians to avoid variables in bounds, but in 3-d no rotation seems to work because I can't rotate that "diamond" shape into a rectangular cuboid. I seem to be missing the core of the hint :(

Comment: Prior to trying the rotation matrix approach, which ended up just being a "summing variables" approach in practice – had a cool "OH" realization moment there – I found myself kind of stumped without separating the integral into several simpler ones, but even that seems to lead me to a dead-end...

Comment: Is there a reason to think that this value is independent of $g$?  It seems this would imply that cross sections of $V$ orthogonal to vector $(1,1,1)$ all have equal area, and I don't _think_ that's true.

Comment: That is, as long as I didn't make a mistake, showing that the integral is independent of $g$ would ultimately come down to showing $(1+x)^2 - 3x^2$ is independent of $x$, which it definitely isn't.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Can you review my post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a fixed $a,b$, the value of $\iiint_V g(x+y+z)\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}z$ can be any real number, so in particular, this integral cannot be written as a function purely of $a,b$ (it still depends on $g$ in ways that aren't determined by only $a,b$).  To see this, consider the following:

First, fix $a,b$, let $g_0$ denote a continuous function such that $\int_{-b}^b g_0(w)\,{\rm d}w = a$.  Define a function $I$ by $I(g) = \iiint_V g(x+y+z)\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}z$ for any continuous $g$, and define $S_w = \{(x,y,z) \in V \mid x+y+z=w\}.$

The key observations are that
$$I(g) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{-b}^b g(w)\cdot \operatorname{area}(S_w)\,{\rm d}w,$$
and $w \mapsto \operatorname{area}(S_w)$ is continuous with
$$\operatorname{area}(S_0) = \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}b^2 \\ \operatorname{area}(S_b) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}b^2.$$

*The rest of the answer is to show how these observations show that the restriction of $I$ to the set of continuous functions $g$ such that $\int_{-b}^b g(w)\,{\rm d}w = a$ is surjective onto $\mathbb{R}$.*

For arbitrary $\varepsilon \in (0,b)$, we consider the functions
$$\varphi_0(w) = \begin{cases}(\varepsilon - |w|)/\varepsilon^2 & \text{ if } |w| < \varepsilon \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
$$\varphi_b(w) = \begin{cases}2(\varepsilon+w-b)/\varepsilon^2 & \text{ if } w >b-\varepsilon \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
which we note satisfy $$\int_{-b}^b \varphi_0(w)\,{\rm d}w = 1 = \int_{-b}^b \varphi_b(w)\,{\rm d}w.$$
For any real $t$, we can define $g_t(w) = g_0(w) + t(\varphi_0(w)-\varphi_b(w))$, and note it's a continuous function that satisfies $\int_{-b}^b g_t(w)\,{\rm d}w = a$.

Now, for a fixed $\varepsilon$ sufficiently small,
$$\begin{align*}I(\varphi_0)-I(\varphi_b) &= \frac1{\sqrt{3}}\int_{-b}^b \varphi_0(w)\operatorname{area}(S_w)\,{\rm d}w - \frac1{\sqrt{3}}\int_{-b}^b \varphi_b(w)\operatorname{area}(S_w)\,{\rm d}w \\ &\approx \tfrac1{\sqrt{3}}\operatorname{area}(S_0) - \tfrac1{\sqrt{3}}\operatorname{area}(S_b) \\ &= \frac{b^2}4 > 0\end{align*}$$

Finally,
$$I(g_t) = I(g_0) + t(I(\varphi_0)-I(\varphi_b)),$$
so $t \mapsto I(g_t)$ is a non-constant linear function of $t$, which means it's surjective onto $\mathbb{R}$.

---

*Afterthoughts*: I forgot to mention, but with a little more work we can compute $$\operatorname{area}(S_{w}) = \frac{(3b^2-w^2)\sqrt{3}}{4}$$

This gives a way to easily compute the integral as
$$\iiint_V g(x+y+z)\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}z = \frac14\int_{-b}^b g(w)(3b^2-w^2)\,{\rm d}w = \frac{3ab^2}4 - \frac14\int_{-b}^b w^2g(w)\,{\rm d}w$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was given this question as a sort of challenge by a friend, but I think he may have got it wrong, then: I just tried performing the integration with $a=3,b=1$ and integrating with $g(t)=3/2$ and $g(t)=15/2 t^4$ and got two different results... (For the protocol I'll state that I wouldn't count on myself to not make silly calculation mistakes, but yeah)

Comment: @AnonA I initially forgot to mention it, but using the same method, we can find a much easier formula for the integral.  See my _afterthoughts_ note.  It should match the results you had found.

Comment: Thanks again, Brian: it did :) That (being the entire process described in your answer) was all a very cool way to think about the problem for me. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

[This is not a solution. This is to explain my comment about the 2-D case, since OP was unable to prove the independence of $g$.]

In the 2 D case, with $ b = 1$ (We can always scale as needed), testing with the constant function $g(x) = \frac{a}{2}$, and integrating over the diamond of $ | x| + |y| \leq 1$ with side length $\sqrt{2}$ gives us $ \sqrt{2} ^2 \times \frac{a}{2} = a $.

How can we show the answer is always equal to $a$ for an arbitrary $ \int_{-1}^1 g(x) \, dx = 1$?
**Hint:** Do the change of variables so that we're integrating along $ y = x + k$, with $ -1 \leq k \leq 1$.
For this line, the starting point is $(- \frac{1+k}{2} , - \frac{1-k}{2} )$ and the ending point is $(\frac{1-k}{2},\frac{ 1+k}{2})$.
On this line, we have $x+y$ varying from $-1$ to $1$, and hence we can apply the $ \int_{-1}^1 g(x+y) d(x+y) = a$.
Finally, integrating across all of these lines (with a suitable volume change), show that the integral is indeed $a$.

Now approach the 3-D case in a similar manner. (To be fair, I've not thought through the details, but I believe it's not that different. OP said that they were unable to come up with a suitable transformation matrix.)

Comment: I agree that given $a,b$, the corresponding integral is not dependent on $g$ for the 2D case, as there we're integrating over a square and cross-sections parallel to a side always have the same length.  The problem with the 3D case is that there we're integrating over an octahedron, and in that case cross-sections parallel to a face don't all have the same area.  Roughly speaking, the triangular faces have area strictly lower than the regular hexagon in the center, so if $g$ is concentrated around $0$, the integral would have a higher value than it would if $g$ were concentrated around $b$.

Comment: Hi Calvin, thanks for the answer! Following Brian's answer, I tried performing the integration with two different functions that fulfill the conditions and seem to have gotten two different results (assuming I did not make some silly calculation mistake along the way (quite a bold assumption, admittedly)). I think my question may have been wrong in the first place (that is, that it might depend on $g$ after all)... I'd love to hear your input if you'd care to provide it. Thanks again!

Comment: @BrianMoehring Ah hm ... That's interesting that it works in 2D but not in 3D. Thanks for digging into this.